# Measuring river width every mile in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, hydrology

Given an area, can Google Earth  tabulate the width of a particular river?

This problem I think requires using an API to programmatically:

1. define an area of interest
2. identify a terrain feature like a river
3. iterate over the length of that terrain feature measuring width

Although it sounds simple and a child could do it using the google earth application and the ruler tool, it seems hard to write code that could do this.

A simpler problem (still hard) is measuring the length of a river and its tributaries in a defined area. Is there a tool in Google earth that can do this?

I realize their API has been deprecated so I am open to another application/solution for this.

Comment: Many datasets already exist. You have been specifically vague as to not state where in the world you want to carry out your analysis. If you are looking for a global network, derived from a DEM then have a look at HYDROSHEDS, If you are in the USA then the NHD, Europe has the CCM.

Comment: thank you for replying. I went to the hydrography site of the USGS here:\However,

Comment: http://nhd.usgs.gov/ and then opened up the viewer and was blown away by all the data sets even in my small town. I randomly picked one and it was a gdb file--USGS National Hydrography Dataset (NHD) Best Resolution for HU8-01070004 20151029 HU-8 Subbasin FileGDB 9.3.1 Current Extent/(-71.899, 42.533), (-71.726, 42.614).  I guess I need to know which file would have river and stream sizes.